# Is it necessary that the injected class should have a spring specific annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control

I have a class called FilterRequest as follows

```
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class FilterRequest {
    Filter filter;
}
```

As you can see I dont have any spring specific annotation on it like : @Component, @Service, @Repository, or @Controller

And I tried to Autowire the same class inside another class like

```
    @Autowired
    private FilterRequest filterRequest;
```

Will it work or not?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It only works if Spring knows about this class. Either use an annotation or register it programmatically using a `BeanFactory`

Answer (score 1):

To autowire your object, spring's entity manager must recognize it as a java bean, and you do that by annotating it with `@Component`.

That way you are telling spring to be responsible for initialize your object every time it's needed

`@Service`, `@Repository` and `@Controller` extends `@Component`

Answer (score 0):

Q: Will it work or not?

A: This will not work. If it is the default configuration and without modification of the library, then this `@Autowired` annotation does not make any sense.

If you want to make it work you should write your own modified annotation and its implementations.

---

These annotations have internal relationships. Using these relationships, spring does some work for you.